# clojure datastructure for mongodb document updating issue

Tags: mongodb, clojure

I have a mongodb document with below structure..

```
{

    "key4" : 

         [
           {"k1":"v1", "k2":"va1", "k3":"value1"},         
           {"k1":"v2", "k2":"va2", "k4":"name"},
           {"k1":"v3", "k2":"va3"}
         ]
}
```

when i was updating this document with given structure..

```
{

    "key4" : 

         [
           {"k1":"v1", "k3":"val1"},         
           {"k1":"v2", "k3":"val2"},
           {"k1":"v3", "k3":"val3"},
           {"k1":"v4", "k3":"val4"}
         ]
}
```

i need output as..

```
{

"key4" : 

         [
           {"k1":"v1", "k2":"va1", "k3":"val1"},         
           {"k1":"v2", "k2":"va2", "k3":"val2", "k4":"name"},
           {"k1":"v3", "k2":"va3", "k3":"val3"},
           {"k1":"v4", "k3":"val4"}
         ]
}
```

which means that if value of 'k1' exist in the new array, it should merge the only object of array into new. 
i am implementing this structure in clojure map.

Comment: you haven't asked a question? Are you looking for suggestions on how to achieve the 'needed' output or do you have a specific problem with an implementation you've already created?

Comment: yes i am looking for the suggestions to achieve the needed output...

Comment: what if the update is missing a key (say "v2"), should it be removed from the answer, or should it be just unchanged?

Comment: then the resultant should have updated value of that key-value pair.. ie : in your case it should be null value for that key..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get very close with a combination of `merge-with`, `map`, and `merge`

```
user> a
{"key4" [{"k1" "v1", "k2" "va1", "k3" "value1"} 
         {"k1" "v2", "k2" "va2", "k4" "name"} 
         {"k1" "v3", "k2" "va3"}]}
user> b
{"key4" [{"k1" "v1", "k3" "val1"} 
         {"k1" "v2", "k3" "val2"} 
         {"k1" "v3", "k3" "val3"} 
         {"k1" "v4", "k3" "val4"}]}
user> (merge-with #(map merge %1 %2) a b)
{"key4" 
    ({"k1" "v1", "k2" "va1", "k3" "val1"} 
     {"k1" "v2", "k2" "va2", "k3" "val2", "k4" "name"} 
     {"k1" "v3", "k2" "va3", "k3" "val3"})}
user>
```

then you need to merge in any items from the longer set.

Answer (score 0):

In your original question, it's not clear whether you are looking for an answer that is geared primarily toward a Clojure or toward MongoDB answer.  I'll take on the challenge of the answer geared toward MongoDB.

There are some tradeoffs depending on whether you are concerned with read or update performance

Your supplied schema embeds an array which is fast for reading but complicates updating, and requires checking of the result and a subsequent second update to push/append.

You can un-embed/flatten the schema if you want to take advantage of MongoDB upsert for a single update/insert request, but then you will have to read muliple documents.

Below please find Clojure/monger code for both approaches, using monger [com.novemberain/monger "1.0.0-beta4"] with Leiningen.

```
(ns FREE-10649-clojure.test.core
  (:use [FREE-10649-clojure.core])
  (:use [clojure.test])
  (:require [monger.core] [monger.collection] [monger.query])
  (:use [monger.operators])
  (:import [org.bson.types ObjectId] [com.mongodb DB WriteConcern]))

;; some operators are missing from monger
(defmacro ^{:private true} defoperator
  [operator]
    (let [op# (str operator)
       op-sym# (symbol op#)]
      `(def ~op-sym# ~op#)))

(defoperator $exists)
(defoperator $mod)
(defoperator $size)
(defoperator $type)
(defoperator $not)

(deftest mytest

    (def initial_doc {
        "key4" [
                { "k1" "v1", "k2" "va1", "k3" "value1" }
                { "k1" "v2", "k2" "va2", "k4" "name" }
                { "k1" "v3", "k2" "va3" }
            ]
        }
    )
    (def data_to_update {
        "key4" [
                { "k1" "v1", "k3" "val1" }
                { "k1" "v2", "k3" "val2" }
                { "k1" "v3", "k3" "val3" }
                { "k1" "v4", "k3" "val4" }
            ]
        }
    )
    (def expected_doc {
        "key4" [
                { "k1" "v1", "k2" "va1", "k3" "val1" }
                { "k1" "v2", "k2" "va2", "k3" "val2", "k4" "name" }
                { "k1" "v3", "k2" "va3", "k3" "val3" }
                { "k1" "v4", "k3" "val4" }
            ]
        }
    )

    (monger.core/connect!)
    (monger.core/set-db! (monger.core/get-db "test"))
    (def coll-name "free10649")

    ;; user-supplied schema
    (monger.collection/remove coll-name)
    (is (= 0 (monger.collection/count coll-name)))

    (monger.collection/insert coll-name initial_doc)
    (is (= 1 (monger.collection/count coll-name)))

    (doseq [outer_key (keys data_to_update)]
      (def array_of_updates (data_to_update outer_key))
      (doseq [object_of_updates array_of_updates]
        (def k1 "k1")
        (def k3 "k3")
        (def v1 (object_of_updates k1))
        (def v3 (object_of_updates k3))
        (def query { outer_key { $elemMatch { k1 v1 } } })
        (def update { $set { (str outer_key ".$." k3) v3 } })
        (monger.collection/update coll-name query update)
        (if (false? (monger.result/updated-existing? (monger.core/get-last-error)))
          (monger.collection/update coll-name { outer_key { $exists true } } { $push { outer_key object_of_updates } })
        )
      )
    )
    (prn "user-supplied-schema updated document")
    (prn (monger.collection/find-maps coll-name))

    ;; flattened schema
    (monger.collection/remove coll-name)
    (is (= 0 (monger.collection/count coll-name)))

    (doseq [outer_key (keys initial_doc)]
      (def array_of_docs (initial_doc outer_key))
      (doseq [doc array_of_docs]
        (monger.collection/insert coll-name (merge { outer_key true } doc))
      )
    )
    (prn "flattened-schema initial documents")
    (prn (monger.collection/find-maps coll-name))

    (monger.collection/ensure-index coll-name { "key4" 1 "k1" 1 })
    ;;(monger.collection/explain (monger.collection/find coll-name { "key4" { $exists true } })) ;; missing explain in monger(?)

    (doseq [outer_key (keys data_to_update)]
      (def array_of_updates (data_to_update outer_key))
      (doseq [object_of_updates array_of_updates]
        (def k1 "k1")
        (def v1 (object_of_updates k1))
        (def query { outer_key { $exists true } k1 v1 })
        (def update { $set (merge { outer_key true } object_of_updates) })
        (monger.collection/update coll-name query update :upsert true)
      )
    )

    (prn "flattened-schema updated documents")
    (prn (monger.collection/find-maps coll-name))
)
```